# How much $\rm CO_2$ stays in the troposphere?

Tags: thermodynamics, physical-chemistry, atmospheric-science, climate-science

I'm trying to make a model which gives the increase of $\rm CO_2$ in ppm for one year, when given the $\rm CO_2$ emitted in one year.
For now, I've calculated the mass of the troposphere using the difference of pression at the surface of earth (1013 hPa) and at the tropopause (200 hPa, altitude 11km).
I also used a coefficient for the absorbed CO2 (Ocean and photosynthesis) of 0.44 in my formula :
$$ ppm_{increase} = \frac{0.44m_{C0_2}}{m_{troposphere}} * 10^6 $$

For 32 gigaton of $\rm CO_2$ emitted in one year, I find an increase of $\rm CO_2$ of 3,3 ppm, which is close to reality, but a lit bit above what's expected. Do you have any ideas of how I can lower this value? Maybe I can add a constant which represents the amount of $\rm CO_2$ lost in the stratosphere?

Comment: Might be a better fit for [earthscience.se]

Answer (score 3):

The Carbon Cycle is quite complicated, and a subject of ongoing research. If you're just trying to build a simple toy model to play with, this isn't a problem, but you shouldn't expect such a model to accurately reflect observations.

A couple of additional issues you might consider, which could either raise or lower the value:

1. Considerable CO2 is absorbed and emitted by the oceans, due to the solubility of CO2 in seawater depending fairly strongly on temperature. CO2 is emitted from the ocean into the atmosphere in the tropics, and absorbed again by cold water near the poles. The balance depends on the equator-pole temperature difference, the speed of circulation of the water (look up the thermohaline circulation), local variations in the concentration of CO2 and carbonic acid (which acts as a buffer for CO2 - the chemistry is non-trivial) in the oceans, and the speed of vertical mixing. This is obviously a complicated process, as the CO2 has to be absorbed at or emitted from the thin surface layer, a process that can be enhanced by wave action, and then diffuse, convect, or be stirred up by sea life deeper down. As the oceans are warming, emission is likely to increase over time. Models/estimates say roughly 92 GtC (gigatons of Carbon, which is about 12/44 times the mass of CO2) are absorbed annually by the oceans and 90 GtC emitted, so the oceans absorb a net 2-3 GtC every year.
2. Animal and plant life absorb (plants by photosynthesis) and emit (respiration and decay) large amounts of CO2 that cause the CO2 level to rise and fall each year with the seasons. A large amount is stored in soil, which consists of plant and animal matter in the process of decay, and the total amount of soil can change. Changes of flow can occur depending on whether it is a good growing season, as a result of agricultural and land management changes - e.g. fire prevention practices have resulted in build-ups of dry dead plant material in forests (absorbing CO2), which eventually leads to bigger and more dangerous forest fires (emitting CO2); irrigating deserts increases plant/animal biomass and soil quality, clearing forests reduces biomass but probably improves soil depth and quality. Increased CO2 boosts plant growth. Life in the oceans has a big effect, too - it forms a carbon reservoir in itself, and when it dies and sinks below the depth where the oxygen concentration drops, it no longer decays and instead becomes seabed sediment. Invasive species could result in significant changes to ocean ecologies, and hence their carbon budgets, along with weather, chaotic predator/prey dynamics, hunting/fishing, disease, etc. Something like 120 GtC flows between the atmosphere and biosphere annually.

It's huge, complicated, non-linear, and very hard to measure. (Like, how do you measure/calculate changes to the average soil depth over a million square miles of remote and uninhabited forest?) It involves small differences between large numbers - a mere 1% error in the measurement of a global 120 GtC flow would have a significant impact on our understanding of the overall balance, and we have lots of inputs that it would be hard to estimate at 1%. More importantly, knowing the size of the flows doesn't tell us how those flows will *change* as a result of internal and external influences, feedback loops, oscillations, varying time delays and time constants, and so on. You have to understand the web of *causal* relationships between them to properly ascribe a cause to any effect.

It is quite easy to come up with proposals for effects that might reduce the rate of increase. The oceans absorb [about a third](https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/news/global-ocean-absorbing-more-carbon) of the CO2 we emit. It is much harder to come up with a *comprehensive* catalogue of Carbon reservoirs and flows to put into a model that we can have confidence is *sufficiently* complete and correct.

Comment: Also, there's the issue of methane.

Comment: ... and volcanoes, weathering of carbonate rocks, peat formation in swamps, carbon aerosols (i.e. soot and smoke from industry and forest fires), CO2 being washed out of the atmosphere by rain... There are lots of more minor effects I haven't mentioned. The Earth Sciences people could probably help more if the OP is serious about building a detailed model of the Carbon cycle.

Answer (score 1):

The atmosphere can be considered well mixed below the turbopause (also known as the homopause) which occurs at approximately 90 km. At this altitude, pressure is approximately 6 orders of magnitude lower than sea level (see standard atmosphere tables). Therefore, slow addition of CO$_2$ will cause very similar changes in concentration throughout the troposphere, stratosphere, and mesosphere which together account for the vast majority of the Earth's atmosphere. So, yes, you do have to consider the amount of CO$_2$ which is added to the stratosphere.

The above does neglect the amount of time required for the stratosphere and thermosphere to mix. This process takes place on the order of years ([according to this article on transport of air between atmospheric layers](https://doi.org/10.1175/1520-0469(1960)017%3C0547:TEOABS%3E2.0.CO;2)), which is short compared to natural and anthropogenic processes which alter CO$_2$ concentration.